# Split a string (stored in a variable) into multiple words using spaces but not the spaces within double quotes

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I'm trying to write a, for me, complicated script where my goal is to do the following. I have a string coming in that looks like this:

```
2012 2013 "multiple words"
```

My goal is to put each of these onto an array split by spaces, but only for single word matches, not those surrounded by double quotes. Those should be considered one word. So my idea was to do this in two steps. First match those words that are multiples, remove those from the string, then in another iteration split by white space.
Unfortunately I can't find help on how to `echo` the match only. So far I have this:

```
array=$(echo $tags | sed -nE 's/"(.+)"/\1/p')
```

But this would result in (on OS X):

```
2012 2013 multiple words
```

Expected result:

```
array[1]="2012"
array[2]="2013"
array[3]="multiple words"
```

How would I go about this sort of problem?

Thanks.

Comment: can you give an example of the expected result? I read multiple times the question about the double quoted words but I dont get it. you want  the quoted words to be a single entry in the array or do you want to split them too?

Comment: Putting values into an array is not a goal, it's an implementation of something you think is the best approach to help you achieve a goal. If you tell us what you're really trying to do, with sample input and expected output, maybe we can suggest an alternative.

Comment: @zekus I've added an expected result. Will look into posted solutions now. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @doubleDown Thanks for editing! Much clearer now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`eval` is evil, but this may be one of those cases where it comes handy

```
str='2012 2013 "multiple words"'
eval x=($str)
echo ${x[2]}
multiple words
```

Or with more recent versions of `bash` (tested on 4.3)

```
s='2012 2013 "multiple words"'
declare -a 'a=('"$s"')'
printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}"
2012
2013
multiple words
```

Comment: +1, I think sometimes eval is a very handy tool. This is one of those cases. This should be accepted solution.

Comment: Thanks so much! I must add that @anubhava's solution is the same, except it doesn't include the `eval` part.

Comment: Is this completely safe?  Any danger of executing commands within `str`?

Comment: @pimlottc, `eval` is not ever completely safe.

Comment: @1_CR I wasn't sure if perhaps the parens acted somehow as a guard in this case.  If not, this doesn't seem like a recommendable solution.

Comment: @pimlottc, take a look at the `declare` technique that I've added, this is safer

Comment: Does anybody know of a pure ZSH alternative that doesn't use `eval`? I tried it and got the error: `declare: a: inconsistent type for assignment`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ grep -Eo '"[^"]*"|[^" ]*' <<< '2012 2013 "multiple words"'
2012
2013
"multiple words"
```

That is, print *only* the strings matching either

1. a quote followed by any number (even zero) non-quotes followed by a quote or
2. a series of characters not containing a quote or space.

Of course, this does *not* handle complicated cases like quotes spanning multiple lines or escaped quotes (using either double quotes like SQL or backslash like the shell).

Comment: What does `grep -V` return?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do:

```
arr=(2012 2013 "multiple words")

echo ${#arr[@]} # gives 3
echo ${arr[2]} # gives "multiple words"
```

**EDIT:** Not sure if it helps the OP but following will also workL

```
str='2012 2013 "multiple\ words"'
read -a arr <<< $str
echo ${#arr[@]} # gives 3
echo ${arr[2]} # gives "multiple words"
```

Comment: It's not that simple if the string is stored in a variable. Can you show an example using a variable?

Comment: @dogbane: Ok I will try to find that but yes fully agree that `It's not that simple if the string is stored in a variable`.

Comment: You've escaped the space in your string and it no longer matches the OP's input. Ideally, you should come up with a solution that splits `str='2012 2013 "multiple words"'` into an array of three elements.

Comment: @dogbane: That's why I said its a `workaround` :P. Only if OP can get the spaces to be escaped inside double quote then it will work. (Can be easily done with a per/sed as well).

Comment: @anubhava I've tried your solutions and `${#arr[@]}` gives 4 instead of 3. Different version of Bash?

Comment: @Zettt: Pls note that I had `'\ '` instead of `' '` inside double quotes.

Comment: Yes, I was that. Then would you like to tell me how I'd have to write the first example to include a variable? I tried `arr=($variable)` and `arr=("$variable")`.

Comment: If you see my EDIT section above. I used `read -a arr <<< $variable` to create an array. I have also created a demo for you: http://ideone.com/Ek6TpZ

Comment: @dogbane: Pls check `eval arr=($str)` response by 1_CR. I believe that satisfies your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

The following will produce the result you want:

```
tags='2012 2013 "multiple words"'
IFS=$'\n'; array=($(echo $tags | egrep -o '"[^"]*"|\S+'))
```

result in ZSH:

```
echo ${array[1]} # 2012
echo ${array[2]} # 2013
echo ${array[3]} # "multiple words"
```

result in BASH:

```
echo ${array[0]} # 2012
echo ${array[1]} # 2013
echo ${array[2]} # "multiple words"
```

works in OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small Python script to parse space delimited csv while respecting quoted fields:

```
$ python -c '
import csv, fileinput
for line in csv.reader(fileinput.input(), delimiter=" "):
   for word in line:
      print word
' test.csv
2012
2013
multiple words
```

Since this uses the fileinput module, works in a pipeline (or a string in a variable) as well:

```
$ str='2012 2013 "multiple words"'
$ echo $str | python -c '
import csv, fileinput
for line in csv.reader(fileinput.input(), delimiter=" "):
   for word in line:
      print word
' 
2012
2013
multiple words
```