# Parse a variable as if it were parameters?

Tags: bash, parsing, arguments

Is there a way in Bash (without calling a 2nd script) to parse variables as if they were command line arguments? I'd like to be able to group them by quotes and such.

Example:

```
this="'hi there' name here"

for argument in $this; do
    echo "$argument"
done
```

which should  print (but obviously doesn't)

```
hi there
name
here
```

Comment: There are some suggestions in this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338863/split-a-string-stored-in-a-variable-into-multiple-words-using-spaces-but-not-t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't store the arguments in a string. Arrays were invented for this purpose:

```
this=('hi there' name here)

for argument in "${this[@]}"; do
    echo "$argument"
done
```

It is highly recommended that you use this approach if you have control over `this`. If you don't, that is even more reason not to use `eval`, since unintended commands can be embedded in the value of `this`. For example:

```
$ this="'hi there'); echo gotcha; foo=("
$ eval args=($this)
gotcha
```

Less nefarious is something as simple as `this="'hi there' *"`. `eval` will expand the `*` as a pattern, matching every file in the current directory.

Comment: I'm getting input from a `read` prompt or a Zenity dialog. Is there any way to get it into an array from that?

Answer (score 2):

I worked out a half-answer myself. Consider the following code:

```
this="'hi there' name here"

eval args=($this)

for arg in "${args[@]}"; do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

which prints the desired output of

```
hi there
name
here
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gsed -r`:

```
echo "$this" | gsed -r 's/("[^"]*"|[^" ]*) */\1\n/g'
"hi there"
name
here
```

Using `egrep -o`:

```
echo "$this" | egrep -o '"[^"]*"|[^" ]+'
"hi there"
name
here
```

**Pure BASH way:**

```
this="'hi there' name here"
s="$this"
while [[ "$s" =~ \"[^\"]*\"|[^\"\ ]+ ]]; do
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    l=$((${#BASH_REMATCH[0]}+1))
    s="${s:$l}"
done

"hi there"
name
here
```