# Passing spaced string as argument to function

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm trying to make an install function like this:

```
function call_fedora(){
        yum -y install $1;
}

function network_tools(){
        tools='net-tools traceroute nmap'
        call_fedora $tools;
}
```

But when I call network_tools function, only `net-tools` is passed as argument to `call_fedora`.  I would like the call to be:

```
yum -y install net-tools traceroute nmap
```

Comment: Surround `$1` with double quotes (`"`) in your first function. Also surround `$tools` with double quotes in your second function.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you're ending lines with semicolons (`;`)?

Comment: @JonnyHenly That's good advice for properly designed functions, but that's not the case here. Quoting `$tools` and `$1` will simply lead to different undesired behavior.

Comment: The `;` I got from an example @Jonny Henly, thank you for point that is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash is actually passing `call_fedora` the entire string `net-tools traceroute nmap` as one argument.  A robust way I know of to do what you want in bash is to use array expansion:

```
function call_fedora(){
        yum -y install "$@"     # "$@"  means  "$1" "$2" ...
}

function network_tools(){
        tools=(net-tools traceroute nmap "some funky package with spaces")
        call_fedora "${tools[@]}"       
                # keep relationship between array elements and args of call_fedora
}
```

The `"$@"` means that each parameter to `call_fedora` will be passed as a separate parameter to `yum`.  The double-quotes mean the parameters can include spaces (it's a good habit to have).

Then, you need to make sure your `tools` are passed as separate arguments to `call_fedora`.  Making them an array makes it easy to keep them separate.  The `"${tools[@]}"` gives you each array element as a separate parameter, properly quoted ([original source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9484942/2877364)).

**Edit** As @chepner points out in his [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41066401/passing-spaced-string-as-argument-to-function/41066534?noredirect=1#comment69340574_41066534), there are simpler, more portable techniques for this use case.

Comment: Since `network_tools` doesn't take any arguments of its own, you could also use `set -- net-tools traceroute nmap "some funky package with spaces"`, followed by `call_fedora "$@"`. This (in addition to dropping the unnecessary `function` keyword) would make for a POSIX-compatible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to replace `$1` by `$@`.